# Generics in Java

Tags: java, generics

I am having trouble to fully understand generics in Java.
I get the initial idea but I don't get it when it comes to more complicated implementations.
For example, in this code :

```
public class TokenCounterMapper 
     extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

   private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
   private Text word = new Text();

   public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
     StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
     while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
       word.set(itr.nextToken());
       context.write(word, one);
     }
   }
 }
```

Why do we have 4 generics parameters (`<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>`)? 
What does they mean?

Comment: I don't understand this example, either.  Where did you get it?  Did you write it?  I see nothing generic here.

Comment: This example is a poor example of generics, especially if you wish to understand them better. You'd be better starting here: [Java generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html)

Comment: Note, this appears to be an implementation of a Hadoop mapper.

Comment: These are compile time instructions that enable this to verify types. At runtime these are stripped out.

Comment: You should accept Makoto's answer; people may stop answering your questions if you do not accept the correct answers.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing terribly complicated about this, but I'm not a fan of this example, so let's use another.

Suppose we wanted to create a data structure that could hold any object.  For that, we have an implementation of `List`:

```
public interface List {
    boolean add(Object data);
}
```

This does exactly what I want.  Well, *sort* of.

What happens when I do this?  What *should* happen?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List list = new ArrayList();

    list.add(10);
    list.add("20");
    list.add(30.0);

    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        int item = (int) list.get(i);
        System.out.println(item);
    }
}
```

This is actually valid Java syntax, and will compile just fine.  The issue here is that I will get an error at **runtime** - I can't cast a `String` to an `int`.

This is actually really bad - if I can't ensure type safety at compile time, then it could be quite a while before I understand the kind of casting error I've made.  Worse, the issue may not manifest itself for a very long time.

Generics on a class allow you to specify a specific type to be bound to an instance of that class.  It also allows you to reuse code in the sense that you don't have to create a specific `List` implementation for `String`, `Integer`, `Double`, `Float`, and so forth.

Let's tweak this interface a bit:

```
public interface List<T> {
    boolean add(T data);
}
```

The resultant code is all good news (and no, it shouldn't compile):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    list.add(10);
    list.add("20");
    list.add(30.0);

    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        int item = (int) list.get(i);
        System.out.println(item);
    }

}
```

First, I can get rid of the cast, which was the problem to begin with.  Since I've type bound the entire list to `Integer`, I don't need to worry about casting it to an `int`.  Second, the error of my ways is made apparent to me **at compile time** - I'm adding stuff that isn't an `Integer` to my list!  That's most definitely a bug, and it's most definitely quick to fix.

---

Generics can compound themselves even further than this, which is why you often see generics going as high as 3 or 4 type parameters.  (If you have any more than that, you should really question if the class is doing too much.)  Their purpose is twofold:

- Ensure that the programmer doesn't have to do unnecessary casts to get back data that they put in.
- Ensure that any errors in inserting incorrect data into the datatype or method is caught as early as possible - at compile time.

There's [an argument about readability](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html), and in my experience, it really depends on what the class is responsible for, as well as the generics (and its bounds).

As a lighter, slightly more intuitive example,  explore the [Guava Tables](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Table) API.  It's all row-key-value triplets, with the idea being that you have some object to represent a row value, some object to represent a key value, and some object that you actually care to store in the table.

Answer (score 0):

So that your `map()` method knows what type of parameter it will receive.